# Surveyor gem breaks my css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, surveyor-gem

I added the surveyor gem and but it breaks my css (built almost entirely with bootstrap). How to deal with this?

Without surveyor:
[image]

With surveyor:
[image]

Below is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

gem "paperclip", "3.5.3"
gem "aws-sdk"

gem 'whenever', :require => false

gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'd3-rails'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'rename'

group :development do
  gem "letter_opener"
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'jquery-datetimepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found here [enter link description here](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor/issues/433). Basically `surveyor_all.css` in `app/assets/stylesheets` is overriding bootstrap somehow.

Just remove `require_tree .` and include your `custom.css.scss` manually. Even without the `surveyor_all.css` being included it seems like that surveys appear fine.

Comment: I don't recommend removing `require_tree .`. It's beneficial to automatically include assets in your asset folders without explicitly stating it. You just have to get the order right. I did `require_tree .`, `require bootstrap`, then `require_self`. Styles that override bootstrap would unfortunately have to be in application.css (self), but I find that better than just removing tree. I've complained about surveyor's reset.css here: https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor/issues/433